# libGDX: Save and load an integer for highscore

Tags: android, libgdx, integer, save, load

I searched for a possability to save an integer, if it's bigger than the second integer (highscore) and load that, if I restart my application. The problem is that I do not know, how that is to do and also did not find a result for my problem, in libGDX, in the web. (I am developing an Android App)

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You can use .prefs files with [Preferences](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Preferences.html). Im sure you will find a lot of examples how to use it

Answer (score 3):

[Libgdx Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) is the best for saving/loading values like highscore.

So easy to create:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("game preferences");
```

For example your highscore is Integer value.
So if you want to rewrite it.

```
    if (currentScore > highScore) {
            prefs.putInteger("highscore", highscore);
            prefs.flush();
    }
```

And load it.

```
  highscore = prefs.getInteger("highscore");
```

Comment: Just be aware that these value are stored as plain text and any savvy user will be able to edit the values outside of the game.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my programm shows me an error.                                                                                                   Can you please give me the code with the correct position (at create, render, update, ...)? Thanks

Comment: Here's the error:Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at de.firstdemo.game.states.PlayState.update(PlayState.java:303)
 at de.firstdemo.game.states.GameStateManager.update(GameStateManager.java:30)
 at de.firstdemo.game.RiskyDemo.render(RiskyDemo.java:33)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

Comment: @Eron can you post your code in question please. Sorry that i haven't answered you earlier.

Comment: No problem. Here it is:                                                                                 public void highScore() {
           if (score > highscore) {
               prefs.putInteger("highscore", highscore);
               prefs.flush();
           }
       }                                                                                                                             I'm running this function everytime, at render()-method

Comment: @Eron and on which line exception occurs?

Comment: @Maxim Ternovitsi at the PlayState (the Class where the game is basically running). I haven't created an extra-class just for my highscore.

Comment: If I write your code in the render()-method or update()-method, I'll become this error. If the code is in PlayState() (the create-method), I won't become an error. Do you know why? I need my code in the render() - method to become my wanted solution.

Comment: @Eron i've explained here why this occurs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46845437/7717409